# about using cpucounter and ramcounter

Tags: c#

how to detect cpuusage and ram usage of a remote host using c#??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the C# PerformanceCounter class to get this done. It's relatively simple to create a read-only counter:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(category, counter, instance, machine)
```

The documentation is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ffskxdc(v=VS.90).aspx

I'm not 100% sure that these are the exact values you want, but these may work:

CPU:

- category = Processor
- counter = % Processor Time
- instance = _Total

RAM:

- category = Memory
- counter = Available MBytes
- instance =  (use String.Empty)

Performance Counters can be very tricky if you want your app to work on all modern MS OSs. Things get even more complicated if you want your app to run as regular (non-admin) user.

But that should get you started.

-- Dan